# MS Web Deploy: configuration section `system.webServer/management/delegation` is missing

Tags: iis, deployment, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have Windows server 2012 R2 with installed Web Deploy 3.5.

I try to deploy my application, but got next error:

[image]

Log file contains next:

[image]

Is there any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "The configuration section 'system.webServer/management/delegation' cannot be read because it is missing schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004797/error-the-configuration-section-system-webserver-management-delegation-canno)

Answer (score 15):

I had installed `Web Deploy 3.6` & `Web Deploy 3.5`. Uninstall 3.6 and reinstall 3.5 solved my problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have just installed Web Deploay 3.6

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was the sequence of installation for management service and web deployment.

You need to install management service first and then install web deployment.

if you mess up the order like I did, uninstall web deployment and reinstall it.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion this issue is most likely an issue with the installation of web deploy 3.6

I noticed that when I installed the component using the web.matrix it do not work properly, you need to use the webdeploy stand alone installer (you can download it from the MS page): first delete the web.deployment 3.6 (reinstalling or repairing do not work), then, click the setup and choose a custom setup installation and be sure to mark all the components from the list. Done.

After this fix you can use web.deployment 3.6 without any issues.

I hope it helps

Comment: Same experience here; Installing WD 3.6 using Web Deploy, I received the error specified by the OP. Uninstalled WD 3.6 from control panel; Downloaded and installed WD 3.6 msi, did not receive the error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is crazy.

I installed Windows Server 2019, followed mostly what I needed as features, no single place had all of what you needed listed.  Then installed 3.6, found I needed more.  Went back and updated 3.6 now it had more to install.  Then I got a similar error, basically schema not found.  I left everything alone, completely uninstalled 3.6, booted, installed 3.6 custom and made sure everything was selected, booted again, bam.. clicked validate connection and came right up.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.