# Error: "The configuration section 'system.webServer/management/delegation' cannot be read because it is missing schema

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I am trying to publish a website from my computer to an IIS web server via web deploy.

I have 3 servers. All servers have installed the same things (Webdeploy etc.) and the services are started (Web Deployment Agent Service and Web Management Service).

On the first server I have no problems on connecting. But the other two servers give me some error when I "Validate Connection" in Visual Studio to the IIS. When I look at the logs on the IIS server, there are my accesses listet with html code 200 (ok).

*An error ocurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. Filename: MACHINE/WEBROOT*

*Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/management/delegation' cannot be read because it is missing schema*

I really have no idea what could solve this problem and hope you are able to help me.

Comment: Note that as web deploy is often used from Visual Studio via the Publish command this question is not actually off-topic and the limit of 5 tags prevents me from adding Visual Studio

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Uninstall and then re-install Web Deploy.

This fixed the problem for me -- the 'repair' option in the installer did not.

Comment: I uninstalled Web Deploy v3.6 and installed v4.0 and its works.

Answer (score 144):

I had the exact same problem, it turned out I had installed Web Deploy 3.6 on top of 3.5. Remove Web Deploy 3.6 and reinstall 3.5 and see if it solves your issue.

You can also try @james-wilkins comment below: "In my case I installed Web Deploy BEFORE installing the management service..."

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out that some components dont get installed propper when using Web Deploy 3.6. 
Uninstalling Web Deploy 3.6 and installing 3.5 helped to me. 
If you want to be on Web Deploy 3.6 you can uninstall 3.5 and reinstall 3.6 (the uninstallation from Web Deploy 3.5 does not uninstall the missed components, so Web Deploy 3.6 works fine when 3.5 was installed before).

Comment: Uninstalling Web Deploy 3.6 then installing 3.5 then 3.6 worked for me after an hour of headache. OS is Win Server 2012 R2. Thank you.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, I removed `Web Deploy 3.5` and re-installed `Web Deploy 3.6`

Comment: I un-installed Web Deploy without SQL 3.6 and installed Web Deploy 3.5 and it worked. I can't believe I didn't try that earlier!

Comment: Errrrrr, so why have 3.6 then ? I give up... but thanks for that, I can now go to bed !!

Comment: In my case I installed Web Deploy BEFORE installing the management service.  I tried to to a "change" on the install to include the management service (or you can add the feature from add/remove windows features), but that didn't help (got the error on this post).  In the end a simple uninstall and reinstall of 3.6 was what worked for me. Seems it needs the Web Management Service to be installed FIRST. Typical MS instructions don't even mention this at all.

Comment: I had exactly the same case as @JamesWilkins.

Comment: All I had to do was uninstall WD 3.6, then reinstall 3.6 using Web PI

Comment: Worked for me too on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: @JamesWilkins comment, "install web deploy before installing management svc comment" worked for me also.  James, I would post this as an answer.

Comment: Ok, answer posted as requested. ;)

Comment: Also you on my Windows Server 2019, I had to **stop** IIS Server (right click server, stop) before uninstalling or the installer would take all the CPU. IMO best way: Stop IIS + Management Service, then uninstall all WebDeploy, then install WebDeploy, then start IIS (Management Service should already be started).

Answer (score 42):

In my case, I installed Web Deploy BEFORE installing the management service. I tried to do a "change" on the install to include the management service (or you can add the feature from add/remove windows features), but that didn't help (got the error on this post). In the end, a simple uninstall and reinstall of 3.6 was what worked for me. Seems it needs the Web Management Service to be installed FIRST. Typical MS instructions don't even mention this at all.

Comment: Exactly my problem. So weird, many of the Web Deploy features are not even *available* during the installation if you haven't installed WMSvc first.

Comment: This is true. Web Deploy must be installed after all. Check the follow link for troubleshooting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-web-deploy-problems-with-visual-studio